# How do I get Amazon s3 private uploads/downloads working in my django views when they work in the admin?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-forms

I am trying to get uploads and downloads with amazon private s3 but am unable to get full circle with it. I have gotten pretty close but it had a but of a funny behavior as noted below.

**What works**

- Upload from the admin.
- Download from admin.
- Download from my template using the my_team view

**What doesn't work**

- Uploads from the views+templates I create won't change the database at all.
- Uploads, oddly, act as the form is valid, and even act like the upload occurred with no change when you look in the admin panel.

** Version **
Django version 1.9.7

**My Relevant View**

```
def my_team(request, challenge):
    """A page showing details of a teams in a challenge."""
    # Find the team that this user belongs to...
    team = Team.objects.filter(challenge=challenge, members__id=request.user.id).first()
    # Boot them out if they are not in any team.
    if not team:
        return redirect('challenges_list')
    special_form = SpecialForm(instance=team)
    upload_complete = False
    # POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        special_form = SpecialForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES, instance=team)
        if special_form.is_valid():
            special_form.save()
            upload_complete = True
    # this template us also used in team-details
    return render(request, 'challenges/team_details.html', {
        'challenge': challenge,
        'upload_form': special_form,
        'team': team,
        'special_form': special_form,
        'upload_complete': upload_complete
    })
```

**My Relevant Model**

```
special_storage = storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage(
    acl='private',
    querystring_auth=True,
    querystring_expire=300,
)

class Team(TimeStampedModel):
    challenge    = models.ForeignKey(Challenge, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='challenge_teams')
    application  = models.OneToOneField(ChallengeApplication, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='challenge_team', null=True, blank=True)
    members      = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)
    name         = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    description  = models.TextField(blank=True)
    special_item = models.FileField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text='File here...',
        storage=special_storage,
    )
```

**My Relevant Form**

```
class SpecialForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ('special_item',)
```

**My Relevant Template**

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ special_item_form }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your `<form>` tag. Without it `request.FILES` will be empty.